# C# Unity: How to reference image effects attached to a main camera via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Title says everything...  How to reference image effects attached to a main camera via script

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add `using UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects;` to the top of your script. The rest is easy. You use `Camera.main` to access the main camera. You can then use `GetComponent` to get the Image Effect script instance.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects;

public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Bloom bloomEffect = Camera.main.GetComponent<Bloom>();
        Blur blurEffect = Camera.main.GetComponent<Blur>();
        Tonemapping toneMappingEffect = Camera.main.GetComponent<Tonemapping>();
    }
}
```